# Is there a node hook that runs AFTER a node is fully inserted into the database?

Tags: 7, hooks

I want to run some code after a node is inserted into the database.  [`hook_node_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) is close, of course, but as the doc says, "when this hook is invoked, the changes have not yet been written to the database, because a database transaction is still in progress".  Is there a hook that I can implement that give me access to the newly-inserted node after it's completely in the database?  [`hook_path_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!path!path.api.php/function/hook_path_insert/7) does this, and is related to what I want to do, but it's not optimal for all sorts of reasons.  Thoughts?

Comment: I've written a module that provides what yor're looking for.
You can find the details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308465/post-save-callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a hook that is called after the transaction is completed, as the code `node_save()` executes is executed during the transaction.

```
function node_save($node) {
  $transaction = db_transaction();

  try {

    // ...

  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
    watchdog_exception('node', $e);
    throw $e;
  }
}
```

If `node_save()` is called from `node_form_submit()` (the form submission handler for the node form), you can add a form submission handler that is called after `node_form_submit()` to the node edit form. It would be executed after the node is saved in the database.

What the documentation for `hook_node_insert()` means is that, since the data are not still saved in the database table, you cannot query a table making a join with the "node" table, as that table still contains the old data; in the same way, you should not call a function that queries the "node" table.

Answer (score 8):

There is another way this can be achievable by adding your custom callback submit function in [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) which will execute after insert/update node.

E.g: 
Check the following code which is for article.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_form_alter
 *
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 * @param type $form_id
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // Checking form_id
    if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
        // Adding custom callback function.
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_callback_on_postsave';
    }
}
```

Now you can do your post save functionality in **_callback_on_postsave** function.
E.g:

```
/**
 * General Callback for form_alter
 * 
 * @param type $form
 * @param type $form_state
 */
function _callback_on_postsave($form, &$form_state) {
    $nid = $form_state['values']['nid'];
    $node = node_load($nid);
    // Do your stuff here 
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but a question: I don't think the "Reverse submit array so newly added submit function should execute at last" line is needed -- won't adding the new callback with the `[]` operator insure that it's at the end of the execution order?  (I've also done some testing that suggest that this is the case.)

Comment: Thanks @JimMiller to point out this, You are right, there is no need to reverse the submit functions, I removed that code.

Comment: This helped me a lot to get hold of the old vid and the new vid at once.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution is to use this module:

[Hook Post Action](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_post_action)

It allows you to use new hooks:

- hook_entity_postsave
- hook_entity_postinsert
- hook_entity_postupdate
- hook_entity_postdelete
- hook_node_postsave
- hook_node_postinsert
- hook_node_postupdate
- hook_node_postdelete