# Shutdown functions not working on php-fpm setup?

Tags: 7

I have a problem with `drupal_register_shutdown_function()`: my callback is not being called =| Here's example code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function example_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'test') {

    drupal_register_shutdown_function('_example_shutdown');
    dpm(drupal_register_shutdown_function()); // This outputs callbacks array showing that '_example_shutdown' really gets registered.
  }
}


function _example_shutdown() {
  dpm('Shutdown callback executed'); // This is not shown
}
```

I use php-fpm, and [php.net register_shutdown_function discussion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#108212) suggests to use `fastcgi_finish_request()` instead of `register_shutdown_function()` with php-fpm. Also, see this D8 issue: ["Ensure register_shutdown_function() works with php-fpm"](https://drupal.org/node/2157053). Is there any D7 workaround?

I think there could be two different approaches:

1. Global: Fix `drupal_register_shutdown_function()` to check for php-fpm environment and use `fastcgi_finish_request()` in that case.
2. Local: Use some hook to force `_drupal_shutdown_function()`. Maybe `hook_exit()` would be ok for some cases, but in my case it is too late (as my callback updates nodes, and by the time `hook_exit()` runs the response is already sent to the browser, so user would get an "old" node, I'm afraid).

Maybe there is something simpler that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example shutdown is getting called ; you can't use dpm in a shutdown function though, because at that point the session already got written to the database and there's just no way to add a new message to it.

In PHP-FPM, the connection also could have already been closed, so print or var_dump is not really a good test to check if you're shutdown function is getting called in general ; it should work in D7 though if you're not using a module that's specifically closing the request, so you should be able to use `print "Hello world";` and get it to show on screen (that's what the core "Shutdown functions tests" is doing in D7).

If you want something realiable to use in a shutdown function to check if it got invoked, try something like `file_put_contents('/tmp/drupal-debug.txt', 'Shutdown function called');`