# How do I update a field value in hook_entity_insert()?

Tags: 8, hooks

I want to update an field in `hook_entity_insert()`. The following code doesn't work.

```
$entity->field_range->value = 'test';
$entity->save();
```

I also tried loading from node object, but still it doesn't work.

```
$node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->load($entity->id());
$node->set('field_range', 'test');
$node->save();
```

After inserting the node only I will get the text "test" dynamically and it won't work in `hook_entity_presave()`.

Any help on how to update an field on hook_entity_insert will be nice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[From this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225612/update-title-field-in-hook-entity-type-insert/225627#225627) we can able to do like below to update an field on hook_entity_insert

```
$entity->field_range->value = 'test';
drupal_register_shutdown_function('_cc_custom_post_insert',$entity);

function _cc_custom_post_insert($entity) {
    if($entity) {
        $entity->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/8.2.x) as in hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update

When saving existing entities, the entity is assumed to be complete, partial updates of entities are not supported.

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function mymodule_node_presave(NodeInterface $node) {
  switch ($node->getType()) {
    case "article":
      $node->set('field_range', 'test');
      break;
  }
}
```

Here no need to load node.

Comment: Hi Ajay , I have edited the questtion, After inserting the node only i will get the text "test" dynamically and it wont work in hook_entity_presave().

Comment: In hook_node_presave() after setting the value on a field also add $node->save().

Comment: I really don't think so there $node->save() is necessary. As hook, itself reveals that "presave" and it will save the respective entity as we pass all values.