# When while saving nodes do I have old and new vid available at once?

Tags: nodes

I'ld like to programmatically trigger some very basic email notification when a new revision of a node is being created. I want to send a link to the compare page `/node/$nid/revisions/view/$old_vid/$new_vid`.

But I wonder on which hook when saving a node do I have the old and the new vid available at once? [`hook_node_presave()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) looks like a dead end to me.

---

This question is not specifically about D7. Though it's D7 I'm using right now, I'ld prefer to find a solution for both D7 and D8.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can add a custom submit callback to the node form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $node_forms = [
    'article_node_form',
  ];

  if (in_array($form_id, $node_forms)) {

    // Add a custom submit callback.
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_MYMODULE_postsave';
  }
}
```

There you can access the original vid from the `$form_state` array. And when you load the freshly saved node you'll have the new vid available.

```
/**
 * Custom submit callback.
 */
function _MYMODULE_postsave($form, &$form_state) {

  $old_vid = $form_state['values']['vid'];
  $nid = $form_state['values']['nid'];
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $new_vid = $node->vid;

  // Voilà!
  dpm($old_vid, 'OLD_VID');
  dpm($new_vid, 'NEW_VID');

  // Do your stuff here
}
```

For reference: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/221041/15055